# Getting null pointer while reading the fileds from JSON to POJO

Tags: java, json, xml, objectmapper

I have my json as given below which is coming as string. I want to map only two fields in SEGMENT object ex:(TYPE and UN_NUM) to a pojo. I used the following code which is returning null values.

**test.json**

```
{
    "TEST": {
        "NAME": "PART_TRAN",
        "VERSION": "9.0",
        "ID": "----",
        "SEGMENT": {
            "TYPE": "R",
            "CLIENT_ID": "----",
            "UN_NUM": "UN"
        }
    }
}
```

**test.java**

```
                  process(new Processor() {
                                @Override
                                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                    String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                    try{
                                        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

                                        JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(data.toString());

                                        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

                                        String value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);

                                        logger.info("Converting XML to JSON {}" , value);

                                        SEGMENT seg = objectMapper.readValue(value, SEGMENT.class);

                                        Test test = new Test(seg);

                                        logger.info("Test Object {}" , test);

                                    }catch (JsonParseException e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }catch (JsonMappingException e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }catch (IOException e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }).
```

**SEGMENT.java**

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class SEGMENT {


    @JsonIgnore
    private String TYPE;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String CLIENT_ID;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String UN_NUM;

}
```

**Test.java**

```
@Data
public class Test {


    private String NAME;

    private String VERSION;

    private String ID;

    private SEGMENT segment;

}
```

**Logs:**

```
: Test Object Test(SEGMENT=SEGMENT(TYPE=null, CLIENT_ID =null,UN_NUM =null))
```

I just added the SEGMENT class which I'm using to map the json.

Comment: How does your SEGMENT class look like

Comment: @YashBansal Just updated the SEGMENT class.

Comment: Why do you use annotation @JsonIgnore

Comment: It is throwing "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field" exception.

Comment: Please remove @JsonIgnore from the properties, please also paste your Test class

Comment: I tried as I said before I'm getting "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field" @YashBansal

Comment: What is exactly the purpose of the @JsonIgnore annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with methods `U.fromJsonMap(json)` and `U.get(map, path)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
    String jsonData = "{\n"
    + "    \"TEST\": {\n"
    + "        \"NAME\": \"PART_TRAN\",\n"
    + "        \"VERSION\": \"9.0\",\n"
    + "        \"ID\": \"----\",\n"
    + "        \"SEGMENT\": {\n"
    + "            \"TYPE\": \"R\",\n"
    + "            \"CLIENT_ID\": \"----\",\n"
    + "            \"UN_NUM\": \"UN\"\n"
    + "        }"
    + "    }"
    + "}";
    Map<String, Object> jsonObject = U.fromJsonMap(jsonData);
    String type = U.<String>get(jsonObject, "TEST.SEGMENT.TYPE");
    String unNum = U.<String>get(jsonObject, "TEST.SEGMENT.UN_NUM");
    System.out.println(type);
    System.out.println(unNum);
```

Output:

```
R
UN
```